# Camera shake effect in iMovie '11

Tags: mac, imovie, macos

Is there a possible way to create a camera shake effect in iMovie 11?

Comment: Why would you **want** that? I've *never* seen a video with camera shake look anything but horrible.

Answer (score 1):

I know that in iMovie HD (2006), the effect was under the name "Earthquake effect". Try looking for it under that name.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make the whole clip into 0.1 second. Then go onto the crop thing in the middle of the screen and pick the Ken Burns effect. Then you have to move the start and the end wherever you want and it will be shaky.